# Angular unit test error : Can't resolve all parameters for ExtConfig: (?, ?)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am new to Angular unit tests. The unit test fails due to an error while running the `ng test` command:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for ExtConfig: (?, ?)
```

How can I fix this error?

**downloadsComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ExtConfig} from 'donwalods-portl';
import { Language } from '../../../language';

@Component({
    selector: 'lib-downloads',
    templateUrl: './downloads.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./downloads.component.scss']
})

export class DownloadsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private readonly configuration: ExtConfig;
    ) {
        this.lang = configuration.instance.languageMap as any as Language;
    }
  // more code
}
```

**donwloadComponent.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ExtConfig} from 'donwalods-portl'
import { DownloadsComponent } from './downloads.component';

describe('DownloadsComponent', () => {

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<DownloadsComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                DownloadsComponent
            ],
            providers: [{ provide: ExtConfig}]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    it('should create the component', () => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DownloadsComponent);
        const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `ExtConfig` provider has some dependencies that are not declared in the `TestBed` module.

You'll have to include those missing dependencies or mock the `ExtConfig` service.

An example of the mocked provider could be the following (remember returning something valid in the methods):

```
export class ExtConfigMock {
    private readonly _context;
    private readonly _instance;
    constructor() {
        // Mock constructor
    }

    instance() {
        // Mocked method, return something
    };
    context() {
        // Mocked method, return something
    };
}
```

and then, when configuring the `TestBed` module, use this mock instead of the original provider:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                DownloadsComponent
            ],
            providers: [
              { provide: ExtConfig, useClass: ExtConfigMock }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));
```

Comment: `export declare class ExtConfig {
    private readonly _context;
    private readonly _instance;
    constructor(_context: ExtensionContext, _instance: ExtensionInstance);
    get instance(): ExtensionInstance;
    get context(): ExtensionContext;
}` These `ExtensionContext` and `ExtensionInstance` are defined in the constructor. I think the problem is that I have not defined it in my `unit test`. How to define or mock it in my unit test code. @Ander2

Comment: I added an example based on your service